A fair set of permutations
Let $P_n$ be the set of $n!$ permutations of the integers $1,\ldots,n$.
A subset $Q\subseteq P_n$ is called fair if it satisfies the following conditions:

For every two integers $i$ and $j$, $Q$ contains exactly $|Q|/2$ permutations in which $i$ appears before $j$, and $|Q|/2$ permutations in which $j$ appears before $i$.

For every position $p$ in the permutation, and every integer $i$, $Q$ contains exactly $|Q|/n$ permutations in which $i$ appears in position $p$.


The grand set $P_n$ is of course fair. My question is: what is the smallest nonempty fair set, as a function of $n$?
When $n$ is even, there always exists a fair set of size $n$, which is optimal. For example, for $n=6$ a possible fair set is: $\{123456, 654321, 345612, 216543, 561234, 432165\}$. It is easy to generalize the pattern to any even $n$.
For for odd $n$ the above technique does not work. What is a smallest fair set in this case?

I assume you are requiring $Q$ to be non-empty.

The smallest (nonempty) fair set for odd $n>1$ consists of $2n$ permutations.  You can construct such a set analogously to the even case:  take the identity permutation $12 \dots n$, the reverse permutation $n \dots 21$, and all of their cyclic permutations.  (Note that this forms a dihedral group of order $2n$; your example for $n$ even forms a dihedral group of order $n$.)  This is clearly optimal, because the two fairness conditions force the size of a fair set to be an even multiple of $n$.
